# NSScrollView how to start from top left corner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite, appkit, nsscrollview

How to set scrollView document view to be pinned to top left corner? If scrollView is big enough/bigger than its content, everything is drawn from bottom to up and it not looks right. I have to override `isFlipped` of scrollView?

I was searching internet and overriding `isFlipped` to return `true`is not everything. I don't want to make my documentView flipped because then I have to make changes in that class to make everything looks like I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created simple `NSView` class as an container for elements that i want to have inside my scrollView and everything looks perfect. I hope this will help someone!

```
@interface FlippedView : NSView

@end
```

and implementation:

```
@implementation FlippedView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
}

- (BOOL) isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** Method to invert axises :

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381180/5464805 thank's to Ben Leggiero :

```
import Cocoa

class FlippedView: NSView {
    override var isFlipped: Bool { return true }
}
```

Then in the storyboard, set this class to the `NSView` below the `NSClipView` and it do the trick. 
However it won't appear in StoryBoard so you'll have to build and run